# solr use both n-gram search and default search

Tags: solr, n-gram

I'm trying to create a corpus using Solr. I have a field named "content" and I need to index and search bigrams and trigrams. Also need to index and search using the default searching.
How to configure these things?

Comment: What do you mean by 'default searching'? As I understand there was already some work done on that, so is there some specific issues? Or is there a need of some generic advice on such 'bigrams/trigram/exact' index/search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to add the [ShingleFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory) to your field definition, after the tokenization has been performed. You can configure the ShingleFilter to generate bigrams or trigrams.

There is no such thing as "default searching", but the bundled schema includes a field named text_general that might be a good match for regular search. You'll have two different fields, one for searching shingles (where you'd want to match the whole bigram / trigram, probably), and one for the "regular search".

You can add the same content to both fields by using a `copyField` directive, such as `<copyField source="content" dest="content_ngrams" />`. You can use `qf` when querying to say which field you want to query, or if you want to score the fields differently for matches (i.e. boosting a match in a bi/trigram). You could also query for a direct match with `fieldname:value`, depending on how you need to query the index.